# Is Angular Material is similar to bootstrap framework?

Tags: angular-material

I am very new to Angular Material, Examples from the official site are bit confusing. About angular my understanding is it's not a grid based it uses the core css flex box concept. so wanted to know whether the purpose of having Angular Material is just like any other responsive frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Angular Material` is not like `Twitter Bootstrap`, the layout design on `Angular Material` is based on flex sizes to help distribute the size of the elements for each siblings contained in an element, in the other hand in `Twitter Bootstrap` is based through grid.. which you can see them with classes like `col-md-6`, besides.. `Twitter Bootstrap` is a package with `css` and `javascript` files that helps you organize your styles of the page and add features like animations and components like `Modal`..

`Angular Material` does use `css` and `javascript` but this one compiles the style directives so you can use `md-content, md-menu` etc.. everytime you add a new directive `Angular Material` will compile the style so the browser can display it properly.. Remember that `Angular Material` is dependent of `Angular` in order to work.. it also has directives for responsiveness and can easily adapt to other screen sizes

I fully understand the frustrations you might get by learning this framework.. due to bit lack of samples and function explanations, i have almost 4 months working with it and i just got used to it.. i can tell all the frustrations and hrs of training was worth

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using the Material framework and so far it's love/hate. IMO it is a responsive framework similar to bootstrap which is more optimized for mobile. The downside so far is that it is more difficult to customize. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720648/angular-material-fixed-toolbar-and-sticky-footer) is a question I've asked on SO regarding Material as an example.